# Find all the values of the parameter a, for each of which the graph of the function is symmetric with respect to the line

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

Find all the values of the parameter $a$, for each of which the graph of the function $f(x) = x^4 -6x^3 + 12x^2 + ax$ is symmetric with respect to the line $x = a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

The graph has the vertical  line  $ x=a$ is a symetry axis if only if for each one of its points $ (x,f(x)), $  its symetric

$ (2a-x,f(x) ) $ is also in the graph.

So, the condition is

$$(\forall x \in\Bbb R)\;\; f(2a-x)=f(x)$$

In particular, taking $x=0,$ we find

$$f(2a)=a^2(16a^2-48a+50)=f(0)=0$$